# Trying to use Excel SUBSTITUTE function to remove spaces - not quite working?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I've looked at some other posts, but can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

I have Column E which starts at 8, and it is a list of vehicle registration numbers.

I want to force the removal of any spaces that appear in this box, so that it will be one continuous VRN.

i.e.: SL54 YNE becomes SL54YNE

I've used the SUBSTITUTE function:

=E8=SUBSTITUTE(E8," ","")

but it doesn't seem to work? I'm sure I had it automatically removing the spaces at one point, now it doesn't seem to do it any more. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOBMq.png)

Comment: Why did you included `E8=`? Try just `SUBSTITUTE(E8," ","")`.

Comment: That was what I was told to do. :)

I've done that, it brings the stop error up, but I'm sure that I previously had the function delete the space? This doesn't seem to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With data in **E8**, in **F8** enter the formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(E8," ","")
```

[image]

Your posted formula would just return *TRUE* or *FALSE*

Comment: I am certain at one point though, having used Data Validation in the column affected, that it actually changed and removed the space once you hit 'return' on that cell?

Comment: *Data Validation* would check if the cell **contained** any space(s), it would not actually remove the space(s).

Comment: How would I use the SUBSTITUTE to actually make that change upon hitting 'return'?

Comment: @CalY If you were entering data in column **E** and wanted Excel to automatically remove spaces in the data, you would use an *Event Macro*. This would behave like a spell-check.

Comment: Gotcha. Our systems are locked down for macros unfortunately. Oh! I've just realised why it was changing and well done on reminding me. I have macro access, so I ran a script, but forgot that was the cause and not the actual formula. Ah well, at least it'll annoy the users with an error until they fix it. Cheers!